# Multi-line bullet list item in Markdown

Tags: markdown

Does Markdown support bullet list items on multiple lines (with newlines inside the item's source)? In HTML, I can put `<br>` inside it.

- Item 1 first line

  Item 1 second line
- Item 2 first line

  Item 2 second line

---

**UPDATED in Jan 2020**

Thank you for your contribution. Two trailing spaces work in the Jupyter environment.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Two spaces at the end of line are used to insert a line-break.

Example (replace the two dots with two spaces!):

```
* Item.. 
some indented text
```

This will render as:

- Item
  some indented text

Comment: For those with auto whitespace trimming turned on (which I believe is very useful), consider using the trailing backslash solution mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 68):

Alternative to **double trailing space** you can add a **trailing backslash**.

```
* Item 1\
blah blah blah
* Item 2\
blah blah blah
```

rendered to

```
* Item 1
  blah blah blah
* Item 2
  blah blah blah
```

Comment: In the Jupyter notebook markdown environment, backslash does not work.

Comment: I prefer this because trailing spaces could be deleted by some editor configuration or simply not recognized by an author.

Comment: python-markdown does not understand last backslash

Answer (score 63):

A more markdown-friendly alternative (to accepted answer) is to add 2 trailing spaces to the first line.

Comment: Nice... didn't know this

Answer (score 5):

Oh I just checked `<br>` also works in markdown too...

Answer (score 1):

You may check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084904/r-markdown-bullet-list-with-multiple-levels/73633161#73633161).

```
    * unordered list
    + sub-item 1 
    + sub-item 2 
        - sub-sub-item 1
        
* unordered list
    + sub-item 1 
    + sub-item 2 
        - sub-sub-item 1
```