# R Markdown Bullet List with Multiple Levels

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/rmarkdown-2.0.pdf

The cheat sheet above lists the following syntax to generate a bulleted list in R Markdown. `*` is the primary solid bullet. `+` is a secondary hollow bullet. And `-` is a tertiary solid square.

`* unordered list 
  + sub-item 1 
  + sub-item 2 
    - sub-sub-item 1`

After I render the output with knitr I don't get the expected output. I get what's shown below. The second and third lines are not indented. Only the very last line is indented, and only one indent instead of the expected two. And *all* bullets are the secondary *hollow* style. It's as if I put the following syntax into R Studio, but I didn't.

`+ unordered list 
+ sub-item 1 
+ sub-item 2 
  + sub-sub-item 1`

How do I get what I intended, the first chunk of pasted syntax?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For each sub-level instead of one tab, include two:

```
* unordered list
    + sub-item 1 
    + sub-item 2 
        - sub-sub-item 1
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

See the Pandoc documentation [under Block content in list items](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#block-content-in-list-items).

Answer (score -1):

Was looking for the same, you may do also something like

```
    <body>
  <h3>Today's shopping list:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Eggs</li>
      <li>Cereal</li>
      <li>Fruit</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

This [link](https://monashbioinformaticsplatform.github.io/2017-11-16-open-science-training/topics/rmarkdown.html) may help too as well.